# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not set scopes in GoogleApiClient.Builder when using Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, drive, android-googleapiclient

I am using drive api with authentication api. I need to login to google account first then upload files to drive. Problem is when i use only drive api without authentication is says unable to sign in. I signed in first using

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 4);
```

it logged in successfully. But when i try to use drive api with this it gives error. Following is the code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 4);
```

Any solution how i can login first then add files to drive?

Comment: Can you please include your `onConnectionFailed` callback?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

Then set the connection code for authorization to occur:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

I am following the documentation - [Authorizing Android Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth), this documentation also provide give on how to handle ff the user has not previously authorized the application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason this code is not working anymore... Looks like the name wasn't the only thing they changed to Google Drive. I was trying the question approach trying to fix it but it's raising the same error as his. Any idea how it's working now?